# jquery bad measure of element

Tags: jquery, html

I´ve got a problem with my code

```
$(window).ready(function(){
        var father = $('.action').offset().left;
var fatherw = $('.action').width();
var children = $('.second').offset().left;
var childrenw = $('.second').width();
var child = $('.second');
var parent = $('.action');

var fpos = fatherw / 2;
var corr = father + fpos;
var correct = corr + (childrenw/2 + 40);
var correct2 = corr + (childrenw/2 - 95);

if($(window).width() > 1100){
    child.css('left',correct);
}
else{
    child.css('left',correct2);
}
```

});

Here I`m trying to center this

```
<header>
        <div class="menu">
            <img src="images/**">
        </div>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/**">
        </div>
        <ul>
            <img src="images/**" class="cross">
            <a href="index.php">
                <li>****</li>
            </a>
            <li class="action">SERVICIOS
                <ul class="second">
                    <a href="**"><li>*** WEB</li></a>
                    <a href="**"><li>****</li></a>
                    <a href="***"><li>*********</li></a>
                    <a href="****"><li>******</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <a href="****">
                <li>**</li>
            </a>
            <li class="****">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
    </header>


.second{
        position: static;
        margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
        text-align: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        z-index: 10;
        width: 100%;
    }
    header ul{
        display: none;
        width:100%;
        position: fixed;
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
        top: 0px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        height: 100%;
        margin:0;
    }
    header ul li{
        display: list-item;
        margin-top: 30px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 26px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

This code works perfectly and it centers perfectly the class action element to the second class element.

After I go to another page on my website, the jquery seems to get bad measures of the window width but if I reload the page, It gets the measures again and works fine. How do I make to make it work from the very best time?

I've already tried to put the script call at the bottom of the html document and it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried changing `$(window).ready` to `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @Justinas yup my lady